# Add CSS Class to link based on Character Count with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have links that load dynamically onto a background to make them look like buttons. Some of the links take up two lines and some of the links take up 1 line. Eithe way they need to be vertically centered.

My plan to to append a class based on the number of characters and then adjust the padding from there.

So if the link's text is 25 characters (including spaces) or less - append class 'small'

if the link's text is greater than 25 characters - append class 'large'

How would I go about doing this with jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#backgroundID a").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass($(this).text().length > 25 ? "large" : "small");
  });
});
```

If you wanted all links, just change the selector to `$("a")`.  You mentioned dynamic loading but not exactly what dynamic meant...if you're loading via ajax, for example [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you could do this:

```
$.ajax({
  //options...
  success: function(data) {
    //do stuff with links
    $("a", data).each(function() {
      $(this).addClass($(this).text().length > 25 ? "large" : "small");
    });
  }
});
```